# softlayer api: How can I get the initial vpn password by softlayer api?

Tags: api, passwords, vpn, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I'm developing a program about softlayer api, and I have a problem with get vpn password.

I call [SoftLayer_Account::getPptpVpnUsers](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getPptpVpnUsers) function and [SoftLayer_Account::getSslVpnUsers](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getSslVpnUsers) function to get vpn information. However, the returned password in the result has been Hash.

I test a lot of method, but noting to get about the initial vpn password. I want to get the method to get the initial vpn password by softlayer api.

regards~

As follows:[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is not way to get VPN Password, you can only update it using the below method:

- [SoftLayer_User_Customer::updateVpnPassword](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_User_Customer/updateVpnPassword)